# Best way to set up a custom WebHook Receiver in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webhooks, handler

We're looking to set up a WebHook receiver in our asp.net application. We've already got a simple aspx document that is able to receive and process the WebHook on the server side when it's received.

While this works, we're pretty sure an aspx file that just grabs and processes whatever is sent to it isn't the best option security-wise. Also, it doesn't need to serve a aspx document back so we figure that's probably a waste of resources.

In the process of looking for alternatives, we've found the following:

[The Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers NuGet Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/webhooks/receiving/receivers) - After some research we discovered that the documentation for this isn't great and every once in a while you'll see mentions of Azure which we don't use. Makes it even more confusing.

[Using a handler to do the processing instead of an aspx page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/http-modules-handlers) - We thought maybe a handler would be able to run just on the server side when a POST is received so we don't need to send a whole aspx page back. This doesn't appear to be a common use for these though.

Any search tips or things we may be missing?

Comment: Did you get any workaround?